# How to insert data in view , select the last inserted id and insert it into another table

Tags: mysql

I want some help please:
I'm solving an exercice using the mysql commande prompt in phpmyadmin
The structure of the view and the table :
The view
Poste_0(nposte,nomposte,indip0,typeposte,nsalle,ad)
And the table segment(indip,nomsegment,etage,ad)

I want to get the last inserted indip0 from poste_0 and insert it into indip of segment table
Hope you understand me

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help clarify.

Comment: for example i want to insert this ligne into the view: (p1,poste1,120,type1,salle1,ad1) now i want the value of indip0 wich is 120 to be inserted into a ligne in the table segment in indip column like this (120, ' ','0',' ')

Comment: Define last....

Comment: What do u want to know more